# Java + SQL : INSERT INTO doesn't works

Tags: java, sql, commit, autocommit

I am a beginner on Java and I am having a problem inserting into a HSQLDB table.

I want this code to add an entry in the VEHICLE table.

But after launching thic code, no new line appears in table `VEHICULE`, and I don't have any error message in the console.

In console, I can read the result of println() :
 VehiculeDAO 85 : vehicule query :  `INSERT INTO VEHICULE (MARQUE, MOTEUR, PRIX, NOM, ID) VALUES ('2','2','14322.429728209721','tbsyfewdfj','52')`

Here is my code

```
package fr.ocr.dao.implement;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.List;

import fr.ocr.dao.DAO;
import fr.ocr.sql.HsqldbConnection;
import test.database.Main;
import voiture.Marque;
import voiture.Vehicule;
import voiture.moteur.Moteur;
import voiture.option.Option;

public class VehiculeDAO extends DAO<Vehicule>{

  Connection connect;
  String query = "";

  public VehiculeDAO(Connection conn) {
    super(conn);
    connect = conn;
  }

  public boolean create(Vehicule obj) {
    boolean action = false;
    try {

      // Table vehicule
      Statement state = connect.createStatement(
          ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
          ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
      String queryVeh = "INSERT INTO VEHICULE (MARQUE, MOTEUR, PRIX, NOM, ID)" +
                " VALUES ("
                + "'" + obj.getMarque().getId() +"',"
                + "'" + obj.getMoteur().getId() +"',"
                + "'" + obj.getPrix() +"',"
                + "'" + obj.getNom() +"',"
                + "'" + obj.getId()
                + "')";

      System.out.println("VehiculeDAO 85 : vehicule query : \n" + queryVeh);
      ResultSet resVeh = state.executeQuery(queryVeh);

      resVeh.close();
      state.close();
      }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return action;

  }
}
```

However  the database is functional and returns its tables and contents during this SELECT query example in another .java file :

```
  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:"
      + path + "VEHICULE", "SA", "");
  String[] tablesnames = { "marque", "type_moteur", "moteur",
      "option", "vehicule_option", "vehicule" };

  for (String table : tablesnames) {
    Statement state = conn.createStatement();
    System.out.println(("\nContenu de la table : " + table)
        .toUpperCase());
    ResultSet result = state.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + table);
    ResultSetMetaData resultMeta = result.getMetaData();

    String columnSeparator = "", rowSeparator = "";
    for (int i = 1; i <= resultMeta.getColumnCount(); i++) {
      columnSeparator += "********************";
      rowSeparator += "--------------------";
    }
```

The problems is the same if I use `PreparedStatement`.

I don't have any error in console and nothing added to VEHICULE table :

```
public boolean create(Vehicule obj) {
  boolean action = false;
  try {

    Statement state = connect.createStatement(
        ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
        ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    PreparedStatement prepare = connect
        .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO VEHICULE (MARQUE, MOTEUR, PRIX, NOM, ID) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    prepare.setInt(1, obj.getMarque().getId());
    prepare.setInt(2, obj.getMoteur().getId());
    prepare.setDouble(3, obj.getPrix());
    prepare.setString(4, obj.getNom());
    prepare.setInt(5, obj.getId());
    System.out.println("VehiculeDAO 85 : prepare : " + prepare);
    Integer resVeh = prepare.executeUpdate();
    System.out.println("VehiculeDAO 85 : prepare.executeUpdate() : " + resVeh);
```

In console I get :

VehiculeDAO 82 : prepare : org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement@55e71685[sql=[INSERT INTO VEHICULE (MARQUE, MOTEUR, PRIX, NOM, ID) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)], parameters=[[2], [2], [15016], [qtrqphfrur], [52]]]

VehiculeDAO 84 : prepare.executeUpdate() : 1

I've tried this : no console error and nothing added :

```
state.executeUpdate(queryVeh);
```

And also this : no console error and nothing added :

```
try ( final PreparedStatement ps = connect.prepareStatement(
    "INSERT INTO VEHICULE ( MARQUE, MOTEUR, PRIX, NOM, ID ) VALUES ( ?,?,?,?,? )" ) )
{
ps.setInt(1, obj.getMarque().getId() );
ps.setInt(2, obj.getMoteur().getId() );
ps.setDouble(3, obj.getPrix() );
ps.setString(4, obj.getNom() );
ps.setInt(5, obj.getId() );
System.out.println("VehiculeDAO 53 : vehicule query : \n" + ps);
//      return ps.executeUpdate();
ps.executeUpdate();

} catch (SQLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In console, println returns :
VehiculeDAO 53 : vehicule query : 
org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement@680836d5[sql=[INSERT INTO VEHICULE ( MARQUE, MOTEUR, PRIX, NOM, ID ) VALUES ( ?,?,?,?,? )], parameters=[[2], [2], [19519], [pzqazmngln], [52]]]

Thanks all for help, I really don't understand, it certainly comes from somewhere else ....?!

EDIT 2 ------------------------------------------------------------------

I found a solution, adding

```
this.connect.setAutoCommit(false);
```

before preparedStatments, and at the end to execute :

```
this.connect.commit();
```

Thanks for help !

Comment: Use a `PreparedStatement` instead and try again.

Comment: *seems to be the same if I use preparedstatement* can you try ?? and post the tried code here, instead of guessing ?

Comment: Use `executeUpdate` and not `executeQuery`

Comment: and don't use resultset for inserts, updates.

Comment: Don't concatenate values into a query string, it leaves your code open to SQL injection, which is unsafe. Please learn how to use prepared statements with parameters.

Comment: This shouldn't compile, your `catch` block matches the start of the method, not the start of the `try` block . Also `executeQuery` on an INSERT query should give `java.sql.SQLException: executeQuery method can not be used for update.`

Comment: Thanks but I tried all solutions without result, no error in console and no new entry in the table. I updated the post with all solutions / corrections offered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public int create( final Vehicule obj )
{
  try ( final PreparedStatement ps = connect.prepareStatement(
        "INSERT INTO VEHICULE ( MARQUE, MOTEUR, PRIX, NOM, ID ) VALUES ( ?,?,?,?,? )" ) )
  {
    ps.setInt(1, obj.getMarque().getId() );
    ps.setInt(2, obj.getMoteur().getId() );
    ps.setDouble(3, obj.getPrix() );
    ps.setString(4, obj.getNom() );
    ps.setInt(5, obj.getId() );
    System.out.println("VehiculeDAO 85 : vehicule query : \n" + ps);
    return ps.executeUpdate();
  }
  catch (SQLException e)
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return 0;
  }
}
```

It uses `PreparedStatement`, returns number of rows affected, (0 on error).
On some JDBC drivers it prints out the final SQL query, but some drivers do not implement `Statement.toString()` and it outputs only the `?` instead of the actual values...
I was just guessing the types, based on your query's output...

Comment: Thanks for your correct guessing and help but it didn't solved this issue. As you can see (I edited my post) it retunrs "VehiculeDAO 84 : prepare.executeUpdate() : 1" → but now new line is added in the table :/

Comment: @kobano BTW after reading your solution, it seems to me that the problem is that you do not close the `Connection`... Thus the original statement has been run, but not committed...

Answer (score 5):

You should use `statement.executeUpdate()` instead of `statement.executeQuery()`.

Documentation of `java.sql.Statement#executeUpdate(String)` says:

> "[...] Executes the given SQL statement, which may be an INSERT,
>   UPDATE, or DELETE statement or an SQL statement that returns nothing,
>   such as an SQL DDL statement [...]"

Comment: I like that this is both correct and succinct.

Comment: Thanks for this information, but as you can see in my post that I edited, it doesn't creates a new line in the table :/